# Calculate spreadsheet from left to right

Tags: powershell

Is there a practical way to:

- open a spreadsheet
- refresh all sheets from left to right
- save it

programatically using Powershell ?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Yes this is possible i'm sure. Might have an issue trying to figure out the left to right of the sheets.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate Excel (which requires Excel to be installed on the machine you're running the script on, of course):

```cs
$excel = new-object -comobject Excel.Application

$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$excel.Visible = $false   # change to $true if you want see what's happening

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("myfile.xlsx")
foreach ($sheet in $workbook.Worksheets) { $sheet.Calculate() }
$workbook.Save()
$excel.Quit()
```

The "left-to-right" aspect is covered by the fact that enumerating the sheets will give them in left-to-right order.

Note that if your sheets depend on external data, this is not enough -- you will also need to refresh all the data from external connections:

```cs
foreach ($connection in $workbook.Connections) { $connection.Refresh() }
```

Because connections are not specific per sheet, the order in which data gets updated isn't defined unless you somehow take care to carefully create the connections in order (or give them specific names that allow you to correlate them to sheets).